# Passing data from Angular never reaches c# controller

Tags: c#, angular

I have an Angular component method that is supposed to pass data to a c# Controller. I am able to get data from the controller into Angular fine, but for some reason sending data to the controller returns nothing, and no error on either the c# side or the Angular. What am I doing wrong?

**Component**

```
import { GcUser } from '../greencard/gcuser';
import { Component, Input, SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core'; 
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { FormControl,FormGroup,Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs'; 
import { GreencardComponent } from '../greencard/greencard.component';
import { catchError, map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators'; 

export class UserDetailComponent { 

httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type':  'application/json'
  })
};

  constructor(  private http: HttpClient) { 
  } 

  updateUser(x:string): Observable<{}>{ 
    //this.http.post('http://localhost:52008/GreenCard/AngAddUser', {u:JSON.stringify(x)}, this.httpOptions );
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:52008/GreenCard/AngAddUser?u='+JSON.stringify(x), this.httpOptions )
    .pipe(
      catchError(this.handleError('updateUser', x))
    );
  }
```

**C# controller method**

```
[HttpGet]
public void AngAddUser(string u)
{
    throw new Exception(u);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My angular component needed to subscribe to the result, otherwise the request was never sent. I wound up doing this:

```
this.http.get<string>('http://localhost:52008/GreenCard/AngAddUser?firstname=woohoo')
.pipe(map(res => <string> res),
  catchError(this.handleError('updateUser', x)))
  .subscribe(events => {this.updateUserResponse = events;});
```